# Unable to use keyboard for input in UIAlertView

Tags: ios, uialertview

Recently I used a `UITextFied` in a `UIAlertView` to prompt the user to input password. But after the `UIAlertView` is presented, I found that the keyboard was overlapped/overlaid by some layer and I cannot type anything through the keyboard.

Can you tell me how to fix this ? Thanks a lot.

![The Screenshot of the UIAlertView ][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMvMz.png

Answer (score 1):

Please don't subclass or mess with the elements inside a UIAlertView.  [Apple's documentation says this:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006802-CH3-DontLinkElementID_2)

> **Subclassing Notes**
>
> The UIAlertView class is intended to be used as-is
> and does not support subclassing. The view hierarchy for this class is
> private and must not be modified.

You need to create your own UIView (with a text field and buttons) that you can add as a subview over and on top of anything else in the view that's currently visible.